# Why does my python egg not work? - No distributions at all found for 

Tags: python, distribution, pip, egg

I have made a distribution of my python package with the following setup.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from setuptools import setup

setup(name='mypackagename',
      version='0.1',
      description='Tool ....',
      author='Peter Smit',
      author_email='lala@lala.com',
      packages=['mypackagename'],
      package_dir={'': 'src'},
      install_requires=['boto'],
      entry_points = dict(console_scripts=[
        'mypackagenamescript = mypackagename.launcher:run',
        ])
      )
```

I created an egg of this with `python setup.py bdist_egg`.

Trying to install it now with pip gives the following error:

```
bin/pip install mypackagename-0.1-py2.6.egg 
Downloading/unpacking mypackagename-0.1-py2.6.egg
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement mypackagename-0.1-    py2.6.egg
No distributions at all found for mypackagename-0.1-py2.6.egg
```

Storing complete log in /home/peter/.pip/pip.log

The mentioned log files showed that it tries to download the package from pypi, where it obviously does not exist.

What did I do wrong? How can I install this egg of mine plus it's dependencies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why not using [setuptools](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools) `easy_install`?

```
easy_install mypackagename-0.1-py2.6.egg
```

If you want to work with eggs that's the way.

Comment: `easy_install` has pretty much been superseded by `pip`.

Comment: @Noufal Ibrahim: so? Isn't question about installing a local egg? `easy_install` does it, moreover installing setuptools it is a matter of seconds, `virtulenv` installs it by default and it's use is far from beign deprecated ATM.

Comment: I don't know whether setuptools or distribute was used to create the egg but that's a separate question. The questioners main point was about pulling in dependencies for which an egg is not necessary at all. All you have to do is run the `install` command and it will pull in the dependencies. I wouldn't recommend using easy_install since the general python community has been moving away from it, eggs and the rest.

Comment: Questioner code, 3rd line: `from setuptools import setup`... and the question is always on eggs... if someone asks about driving a chariot you answer _Hey, don't you know we moved to cars? Use them instead_ ^^

Comment: Anyway I'm not a setuptools fanatic, simply its easily available, questioner used it to make egg, easy_install works with local files... why bother with workarounds or changing its working method? Go with easy_install and live with it. I use it to deploy apps on a server with and I'm very comfortable with it: just sftp and easy_install the egg and you're done...

Comment: `distribute` is fork of setuptools that's more maintained. When you say `from setuptools import...`, you're likely to be using distribute (virtualenv uses it by default now). I'm not going to bother with your car analogy. The questioners concern was (from his response to my answer) dependency installation. You don't need eggs for that. As for easy_install, setuptools etc., you're welcome to stick to them but I know that they're deprecated and think it's useful to give questioners the details.

Answer (score 2):

pip [cannot install from eggs](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/#pip-compared-to-easy-install).

If you want your package to be available on PyPI, you need to [register and account there and upload it](http://guide.python-distribute.org/contributing.html). You can then simply say `pip install myproject`. It will search PyPI, find it, download and install it.

If you have your `setup.py` ready and want to install your application locally, all you need to do is to say `python setup.py install`. You don't need to use pip or easy_install.

The [hitchhikers guide to packaging](http://guide.python-distribute.org/index.html) contains details on all these things. It should make things clear.

Comment: I don't want my package on PyPI, as it will be not freely available. Eggs seem to be the way to go, but I want the dependencies being fetched from PyPi. Do I still not need pip or easy_install?

Comment: The `python setup.py install` will automatically pull in the dependencies. You don't need eggs at all. They're a binary distribution format.

Answer (score 2):

Pip cannot install eggs. IMHO that is a serious lack. I would suggest you to try out [Pyg](http://pyg.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html). Just download the `get-pyg.py` script and execute it:

```
$ curl -O https://raw.github.com/rubik/pyg/master/get-pyg.py
$ python get-pyg.py
Retrieving archive from ... etc.
```

**Note**: As an alternative, you can install it via easy_install or pip.

Then you can use it:

```
$ pyg install mypackagename-0.1-py2.6.egg
```

Pyg supports virtualenv too.

rubik

Comment: Yeah it is a new Python tool! It is under heavy development. You can find it at: https://github.com/rubik/pyg. Let me know if you want to be part of the development team! Documentation is hosted at: http://pyg.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html